# How can I permanently disable directory caching in lftp?

Tags: cache, lftp

I attempted to configure my `$HOME/.lftp.rc` to permanently disable directory caching (it has a nasty habit of never bloody updating).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcandre/dotfiles/master/.lftp.rc

But no matter how I try to write this configuration, it seems to have no effect. What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my filename was wrong, it should be `~/.lftprc`.

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.lftprc